# agregar un string al inicio en c

Tags: c, string

> Introducir una frase por teclado. Imprimirla cinco veces en filas
> consecutivas, pero cada impresión ir desplazada cuatro columnas hacia la
> derecha.

Por ejemplo si yo ingreso "hola como estas" el resultado deberia ser

[image: reusltado]

intente con esa funcion pero solo me imprime con espacios hasta el "hola" si hay un espacio lo ignora

```
void strbeg(char* strReceive, char* strInsert)

int strInsertLength = strlen(strInsert);
int strReceiveLength = strlen(strReceive);

for(int i = strReceiveLength; i >= 0; i--)
{
    strReceive[i + strInsertLength] = strReceive[i];
}

for(int i = 0; i < strInsertLength; i++)
{
    strReceive[i] = strInsert[i];
}
```

Comment: El enunciado dice `... cada impresión ir desplazada ...`. ¿ Estás seguro de que lo que quieres es ir insertando los espacios en la propia cadena ?

Comment: @Trauma Tenes razom, podria hacer el desplazamiento con la funcion printf

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionan en los comentarios, el enunciado menciona solo desplazar, por lo que de manera sencilla podrías hacer uso del width specifier dentro de `printf`:

```c
void strbeg(char* strReceive, int times, int space_size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    if (i > 0) printf("%*s", i * space_size, "");
    printf("%s\n", strReceive);
  }
}
```

Comment: que hace esta linea? printf("%*s", i * space_size, "");

Comment: @IvanDangelo imprime "" haciendo uso del [width specifier](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/chp-fmt-1.3/index.html) para lograr el espaciado. `*` indica el ancho que ocupará (`i * space_size`) y `s` la cadena a formatear (`""`).

Comment: Puedes encontrar un poco más de información detallada [aquí](https://devdocs.io/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 0):

> pero solo me imprime con espacios hasta el "hola"

Huele a que la lectura de la cadena se hace con un código similar al siguiente:

```
char cadena[200];
scanf("%s",cadena);
```

El problema que tiene esta lectura es que se detiene al encontrar un separador. ¿Y qué es un separador? Pues, por defecto, cualquiera de los siguientes:

- espacio
- tabulador
- salto de línea
- retorno de carro

Así pues, dado que la entrada `"hola como estas"` tiene dos espacios, la llamada a `scanf` únicamente almacenará `"hola"`, dejando el resto en `stdin`.

Para leer una línea completa es preferible usar `getline`:

```
getline(cadena, 200, stdin);
```

Comment: No recuerdo si la función `getline` en C es estándar, de lo contrario, sería preferible usar [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Comment: @MrDave1999 https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1112 no tengo un compilador a mano, pero parece que sí

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112784/undefined-reference-to-getline-in-c) dicen lo contrario...

Comment: Es ese el error que mencionabas @eferion, la lectura de datos la estuve haciendo a raiz de este problema con gets(string) de la libreria string.h, no se si sera lo mas apropiado pero me funciono